# Which frame ? - Linux framebuffer alternate

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, mmap, framebuffer

I read the Linux framebuffer `dev/fb0` with `mmap()`.

But it is an alternative framebuffer, so I get two images.

In one hand : `char * map0 = (char *) mmap(nullptr, width*height*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);`
In the other hand : `char * map1 = (char *) mmap(nullptr, width*height*4, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, width*height*4);`

The first image is at the position 0 of the framebuffer. The second is just next, with an offset of `width*height*4`, the size of the first image.

Can I know, in live, which one of these two images is currently displayed on the screen?

Comment: Do you really want to read framebuffers directly? I'm pretty sure you're supposed to use CRTCs from DRM these days.

Comment: Yes if possible because I do calculation directly on the frame buffer. I use `sys/mman.h`, `sys/ioctl.h` and `linux/fb.h`. I try to find something in these kind of libraries.